# Reading Realtime Data Into Matlab, then Saving and Realtime Plotting

Tags: excel, matlab, plot, record, xlsread

I am currently trying to achieve the following:

Read real-time, changing, data into Matlab(R2016a), from Excel(2016), saving this information and plotting it while it updates in real time.

I am currently using vba to record the data into excel, and then converting to a csv, uploading into matlab to plot.  However, this is slow and Excel seems to falter after a few hundred thousand lines and I want this to run continuously and update the plots in real-time.

So to reiterate:

1) Read data into matlab from excel and record, say A40:R40, these cell values are static, only the data changes
2) Realtime plot data, the A40 cell value is time(x), the rest would be plotted on (y)

To be honest I am completely new to matlab and am still trying to understand xlsread.  Also, the command codepage in matlab you guys are probably so familiar with is throwing me off.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Reading your question I wonder whether you would like to replace your VBA-recording program by a Matlab/Octave recording program saving the excel/csv workaround. This may be the more direct solution for your problem.

Comment: Currently the data that is fed into excel isn't able to be fed into matlab via an api so the excel 'workaround' that I am using seems to be the only way.  The real time factor involved is okay delayed so the time/resources lost converting into excel and then into matlab isn't really a problem as I have plenty of system resources.

Comment: Then it is not in a strict sense real time data. It is more sort of batch processing. I recommend changing your question in this sense to make clearer what you need. I also recommend that you ask more specific what your problem is. StackOverflow is not a free coding service but every body is willing to help you with upcoming problems while you are trying to solve your problem. So: What exactly is unclear with `xlsread()` function?